# Keras image augmentation with ancillary data

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, keras, classification

I am trying to classify images using two inputs: 1) image, and 2) an ancillary data attached to the image, for example, the original width of the image before it was resized as the input to the network:

```
input_anci = Input(shape=(1, ), name='extra_input')
input_images = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3), name='image_input')

vgg_out = base_model(input_images)  # Here base_model is a VGG16
f0 = Flatten()(vgg_out)
f0 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(f0)
f0 = Dropout(0.5)(f0)

f1 = Dense(8, activation = 'relu')(input_anci)
f01 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([f0, f1])

classidx = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(f01)
model = Model(inputs=[input_images, input_anci], outputs=classidx)
```

In order to do augmentation to the images, I used `ImageDataGenerator`:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 360,
        width_shift_range = 0.2,
        height_shift_range = 0.2,
        shear_range = 0.2,
        zoom_range = 0.2,
        horizontal_flip = True,
        vertical_flip = True,
        fill_mode = 'nearest',
        validation_split = 0.25)
```

Then I defined the train and validation generator:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow((X, X_anci), Y, subset = 'training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow((X, X_anci), Y, subset = 'validation')
```

Then I used `fit_generator` to train the model:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,validation_data = validation_generator, ...)
```

When I ran it, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16-v3x.py", line 265, in <module>
    subset = 'training')
  File "C:\Users\wzhou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 705, in flow
    subset=subset)
  File "C:\Users\wzhou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 1116, in __init__
    (np.asarray(x).shape, np.asarray(y).shape))
  File "C:\Users\wzhou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (824,56,56,3) into shape (824)
```

What shall I do to make sure `(X, X_anci)` is fed into `[input_images, input_anci]` in a right way?

PS. It's my first time posting a question. Hope the formatting is not too bad.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the model architecture code as well, please?

Comment: Just did.  Thanks!

Comment: And what is the shape of `X_anci` array (i.e. `X_anci.shape`)?

Comment: The shape of X_anci is: (824,)

Comment: Well, it is really strange. Your code works for me without errors. I thought maybe there is an inconsistency in input shapes and the shape of your data arrays but it seems there isn't. And there is no problem with the model architecture. As a last check, please add the  full code of `ImageDataGenerator`. Also please mention the version of Keras you are using (i.e. `print(keras.__version__)`).

Comment: Just added the full code of ImageDataGenerator.  My Keras is 2.1.6

Comment: Nope. No problem there either. I'm sorry but could you post the full stack trace (i.e. error log) as well? Which line causes this strange error?!

Comment: Also, if you would like, you can upgrade Keras and see if you still get this error.

Comment: Added the trace, where "line 265" is referring to the train_generator line.

Comment: So it originates from `flow` method. My best guess is that it's due a bug in 2.1.6 version. I am using version 2.2.0 and your code works on my machine. Upgrade Keras and see if it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that - glad to hear that the code is working at least somewhere...

Comment: Upgraded Keras to 2.2.2 and... the problem is gone!  Thanks a bunch!!